# Ignore calls from one class in a bindInterceptor

Tags: java, aop, guice

I'm using Guice to make an interceptor for all methods in one class except the ones annotated with a specific class I created:

Here's the AbstractModule:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        bindInterceptor(
                Matchers.subclassesOf(MyFacade.class),
                Matchers.not(Matchers.annotatedWith(DAO.class)),
                new MyInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Now, is it possible to make my `MethodInterceptor` ignore all methods in `MyFacade` when they are called by another method in the same class (`MyFacade`)?

For example:

```
public class MyFacade{

    @DAO
    public void doSomething(){
        ...
    }

    public void a(){
        ...
        b();
    }

    public void b(){
        ...
    }

}
```

I don't want that the interceptor intercepts the call from method a() to method b().

Thanks!

Comment: I really like this question, since this would be the normal behavior in EJB context. I suppose, you already have a test case proving that this does NOT work as expected?

Comment: Well, it does work as expected since I asked it to intercept all methods from the `MyFacade` class, so I believe it's the normal behavior. So I don't know if it's possible to do what I want. I thought in maybe using the stacktrace in my `MethodInterceptor` but it would be an ugly solution.

Comment: And yes I have tested it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way for the intercepted to know which class is calling it. Also, under most circumstances, you would expect a call to `b()` to run the intercepted method—such as ensuring a DB transaction is opened and closed appropriately. If you need to ensure that interception only occurs on external calls, you'll have to be a little clever.

#### Option 1: Rewrite the interceptor to keep state

Consider rewriting your MethodInterceptor to have a guard checking whether it's in the middle of an intercepted method. Remember, [`bindInterceptor` accepts instances](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#bindInterceptor%28com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%3E,%20com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.reflect.Method%3E,%20org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor...%29), so if it comes to it you can keep call stack state in there. This is unusual—interceptors are typically assumed to be stateless—so document it well.

```
/**
 * Prevents internal interceptor calls from within intercepted methods.
 * Not thread safe.
 */
public abstract class GuardedInteceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  private boolean executionInProgress = false;

  /** No-op if in the middle of an intercepted method. */
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    if (executionInProgress) {
      return invocation.proceed();
    }
    executionInProgress = true;
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
      runBefore();
      returnValue = invocation.proceed();
      runAfter();
    } finally {
      executionInProgress = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
  }

  protected abstract void runBefore();
  protected abstract void runAfter();
}
```

#### Option 2: Rewrite the intercepted class to delegate to a private method

In your situation I would have `b()` delegate to private method `bInternal()` and call that instead of `b()` from within MyFacade. Guice AOP can't intercept private methods, so you don't need to worry about annotating or configuring anything else. This also allows the individual systems to choose whether to call the possibly-overridden-or-intercepted public methods or the effectively-final, predictable private methods. AOP interception is implemented through inheritance, so the standard rules about [designing and documenting for inheritance](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/classes-and-interfaces/ch04lev1sec5) apply here.

Comment: Very good, thank you!! I'll take option 1, because I'm using interceptor to open and close transactions, and whoever in the future do this (call some method in my facade from another method in the facade) probably won't want a new transaction opened! And this way method b() is more reusable.